# Arranging text on a page at a certain pixel

Tags: css, bootstrap-5

I have this div and using bootstrap 5. I want a situation where
when the page is <=1024px I will like to have Description and Length
on their own line.

```
        <div class="col-3 col-md-4 col-lg-3">
            <div class="card d-flex align-items-center dynamic-card mb-3">
                <div class="card-body">
                    <div class="card-title">@Tester.ProjectName</div>
                    <div class="row">
                        <div class="col">
                            <label>Description</label><br>
                            $@Tester.Amount
                        </div>
                        <div class="col">
                            <label>Length</label><br>
                            @Tester.SquareFeet
                        </div>
                        <div class="col d-flex align-items-center justify-content-end">
                            <div class="icon next-button"></div>
                        </div>
                    </div>
                </div>
            </div>
        </div>
```

I was just wondering where and how to write this. Will this be a media query? What will it look like?

Comment: I'm pretty sure you need to add the media query to the `row` class, but without the css and the [Reproducible example](https://stackoverflow.com/help/minimal-reproducible-example) I don't know the exact changes needed, I'd suggest changing the `row` to `display: flex` and `flex-direction: row;`

Comment: So start with something like this and include the css in it right? @media screen and (max-width: 1024px) {}

Comment: Exactly, since you're using bootstrap maybe use a variable to have the `1024px` and create the media query with that

Answer (score 0):

You probably want something like the following

```css
.row {
  display: flex;
  gap: 0.5rem;
}

@media screen and (max-width: 1024px){
  .row {
    flex-direction: column;
  }
}
```

```html
<div class="row">
    <div class="col">
        <label>Description</label><br>
        $@Tester.Amount
    </div>
    <div class="col">
        <label>Length</label><br>
        @Tester.SquareFeet
    </div>
    <div class="col d-flex align-items-center justify-content-end">
        <div class="icon next-button"></div>
    </div>
</div>
```